# AngularJS: Modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say that we have this:

In 'app/app.module.one' I define the dependencies for AngularJS module by passing in the 'app.module.two' module as a second parameter e.g.

```
var app = angular.module('app.module.one', ['app.module.two']);
```

My question is: can I in 'app.module.two' module make use of services and factories from 'app/app.module.one' ??

Comment: I can't say with any certainty, but I'm pretty sure that would create a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you have Services that need to be used in both then you should put that code in a lower level module (like say `app.module.base`) and then both `app.module.one` and `app.module.two` would need to require it (`app.module.base`).

Comment: Thank you. How about routes how do they work when they are defined on a dependency module?

Comment: @edgaraafelix Good question. It's been a while since I used the stock routing stuff. You'll probably want to either test yourself or start a new question.

Comment: I will test it, then I let you know.